# Android QR Scanner not detecting bar codes

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I've used the https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision example to scan QR codes, but I can't get it detect any barcodes. The `receiveDetections` method always returns zero size in if (qrcode.size() != 0) condition. I've tried to change setRequestedPreviewSize and setRequestedFps but with no success. I also created another project from another tutorial, but the same problem occurred.

By the way, the barcode image I'm scanning is valid. I've scanned with working google play app and it does return a value.